# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Network and Settings disappeared

Tags: networking, gnome, 22.04, network-manager, wine

I was installing [Wine](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu), when my internet dropped. I went up to open my settings and check what was wrong, but when I clicked on the settings button in the drop down it wouldn't do anything, I watched the System monitor and a process wouldn't even appear. So I restarted, but once I had restarted the settings button had completely disappeared. After some googling and trying some fixes for peoples similar issues, I've found that the OS thinks neither the network manager nor the gnome control center are installed, but without internet I can't get either. So I went to packages.ubuntu.com and put the .deb for [network manager](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/network-manager) and [gnome control center](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/gnome-control-center) onto a usb stick and copied them over. I try and install them but it says it's not compatible.

My patience for tinkering has run out and I'm at the limit of my little experience and skills. What have I got wrong?